# How to create a fiddle with vee-validate code?

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I try to create a fiddle with  vee-validate 3.0 using ValidationObserver, 
but I encounetred a problem, that trying to add lines :

```
import {ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend} from 'vee-validate'
import {required, email, url} from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
```

I got error in console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This saved with error:
https://jsfiddle.net/a6dL7yfc/2/

How can it done corectly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `import` when you're loading from a CDN. Instead everything is exposed as properties of a global `VeeValidate` object.

For example, `ValidationObserver` is `VeeValidate.ValidationObserver`.

Change these:

```js
import {ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend} from 'vee-validate'
import {required, email, url} from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
```

To this:

```js
const {ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend} = VeeValidate
const {required, email, url} = VeeValidate.Rules
```

The first line should now work but the second will still fail. To fix that you'll also need to change your vee-validate URL to be `vee-validate.full.js` instead of `vee-validate.js`. The full build includes the rules.

If you want to specify a template in the HTML section then the usual caveats around in-DOM templates apply. e.g. You'll need to use kebab-case for the component names in the template: `<validation-observer>`.

Comment: Thanks!
I managed to run this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ub7g4dcj/